# Magnetic field inside a superconductor ring vs a bulk superconductor

Tags: superconductivity

In the book by Rose-Innes, [Introduction to superconductivity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/008021651X) there is an argument that a superconducting ring of area $A$ fulfills

$$
Li+AB_{\rm ext} = {\rm constant},
$$

with $L$ the inductance of the ring, $i$ its current, and $B_{\rm ext}$ an external magnetic field. Now the book says "Even if the external field is reduced to zero, the internal flux will be maintained by the circulating current".

A few pages later it is described the Meissner effect, in which a (bulk) superconductor is always diamagnetic. In particular, if in the superconducting state, there's an external $B_{\rm ext}$ and later switched off, the material remains diamagnetic.

I'm confused with these two cases.

For $B_{\rm ext}=0$ inside the ring, there's a persistent current and hence an associated magnetic field, but in the bulk, it seems that there are no currents (even if the "egg-like" bulk is composed of infinitesimal rings, see the figures).

How to reconcile these two effects?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what is bothering you. The currents on the ring are *surface* currents in all cases. There is never any current  further inside the superconducting material  than the London penetration depth.

Comment: Ok but if there's a surface current then it must exist a tiny magnetic field inside the bulk, right? If $B_a=0$, then this tiny magnetic field still exists?

Comment: No. I don't know what ${\bf B}_a$ is supposed to be (the figure are not understandable) , but  there is no magnetic field in the bulk. The surface currents  exist specifically to cancel the bulk field. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_equations.